# Check User Session in win32 Service

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, service, authentication

I'm creating a win32 service ,I want my Service to check if user is not logged in, my service do something How i Can check if user logged in or not?

Comment: Do you need to check for a specific user or any user?

Comment: At first Step I need to check for any User not Specific User

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WTSEnumerateSessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383833%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to check the connection state ([WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383860%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) of all sessions in the system. If you bother only for the console session you can use [WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383835%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get its id and then call [WTSQuerySessionInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383838%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Also a service can receive [SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683241%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get session change notifications.